# is it possible to stop joins in jpa?

Tags: hibernate, rest, jpa

I have joins defined in my entity class.  When I do a query the join entities come back also.

Is it possible to stop these joins or will they always occur?  In some instances I would like to stop them occurring so that I dont transfer unnecessary associated entities in my transfer objects.  Or is the practice to strip out what you only need for transfer object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to fetch all the join entities on every request, you may use lazy fetching.
This fetch parameter can be added optionally to the annotations: @Basic, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToOne, and @ManyToMany.

e.g. `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

By setting FetchType.LAZY you don't retrieve all those joined fields from the DB, until they are explicitly accessed.

Comment: Thanks.  When I check the collection the associated objects are not loaded but when I add the collection to the response entity I think it must be accessing the associated entities automatically because the response still returns everything.  Do I have to explicit set a transfer object and use something like BeanUtils.Copy to stop this occurring?  Thanks again.

Comment: This could be a solution. If you don't use the linked entities at all at any point of the application, you might just omit the properties that you don't need in the related JPA Entity Bean.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be you create a new Transfer Object and get that from the Database. So, for Eg: If you have Person class and you need some of its properties to transfer, consider doing following

Original Person class will look some thing like

```
Class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    Private Set<User> users
}
```

Create a new Class which will be your Transfer Object, assuming you only need to transfer some of the properties of person class.

```
Class PersonDTO {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public PersonDTO(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName; 
   }
}
```

Now you can write your query as

```
Select new PersonDTO(firstName, lastName) from Person p;
```

**Note**: Corresponding constructor in the PersonDTO is important.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you extend this pattern to work on a lot more fields?  It does not seem appropriate to keep adding the fields you require to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @JsonIgnore annotation to ignore the field from being serialized by Jackson which spring uses internally.